# How to pass into Seq reponse of function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, seq

I want to pass into `Seq([644511,340755])` an response from async function `getProjects`.

So I tried

```
...
var ids = pivotal.getProjects(function (err, data) {
  var ids = data.project.map(function(x) { return parseInt(x.id); });
  console.log("IDS_i: ".red + ids);
});
console.log("IDS_e: ".red + ids);

Seq(ids)
  .parEach(function(project_id) {
....
```

Logs:

```
IDS_e: undefined
GET /stories 200 34ms
GET /favicon.ico 404 2ms
IDS_i: 644511,340755
```

I am wondering maybe I should put this into `Seq`:

```
Seq()
   .seq(function() {
      pivotal.getProjects(function (err, data) {
        data.project.map(function(x) { return parseInt(x.id); });
      });
    }
```

but how to return ids as array in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getProjects` is also async. A basic rule: You can't return any values from an async function. You have to do all processing in the callback function. Execution will continue before your arrays have been aggregated. So your `seq` approach is what you need:

```
Seq()
    .seq(function() {
        pivotal.getProjects(this);
    })
    .flatten()
    .seqEach(function(project) {
        var projectId = project.id;
        myService.someOtherAsyncAction(projectId, this);
    });
```

`node-seq` will take care of passing the result of the callback to the next `seq` step by passing `this` as the callback function to your async function. This is how flow and results are passed to the next step. `flatten` will make sure each `project` is available as individual elements on the stack so you can do `seqEach` in the next step.

Comment: Ok, I understand but have one problem with ``projects.project.map(function(x) { return parseInt(x.id); });`` how to pass it to new step(``.parEach``) as array. I have to put this into the new function??

Comment: You could try `seqEach` instead of `seq` as the second step. You might have to `flatten` the array though so each `project` is considered an element on the stack. I'll update the answer with some pseudo code.

Comment: Thanks, one thing looks like flatten() is not what I need. I can't use seqEach on flatten() because ``this`` is ``[object Object]`` I have to someway set ``this`` as ``this.project`` and then I will get ``object Object],[object Object]``

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but you could try with `flatten(false)`. You can consult the documentation for [node-seq](https://github.com/substack/node-seq) for more details.